# JS best way to increase size

Tags: javascript, assign

The problem is therein, that `element.style.width` returns a string, and not a number.

I want to do increase the width like so:

```
element.style.width += 100;
```

, but it remains the same. My solution is to take one of the long ways:

```
element.style.width = element.offsetWidth + 100;
element.style.width = parseInt(element.style.width) + 100;
```

(Thankfully, it doesn't require `+ 'px'`)

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: It should require "px"

Answer (score 1):

You can do so:

```
var computedStyles = window.getComputedStyle(element, null);
var width = window.parseInt(computedStyles.width, 10);
element.style.width = (width + 100) + 'px';
```

or with `jQuery` you can do like this:

```
$(element).css("width", "+=200");
```

See more about it http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: Jquery is not mentioned in tag

Answer (score 0):

You could also try this, though it is not particularly apposite or compact;

```
element.setAttribute("style","width:" + (element.offsetWidth + 100) + "px");
```

[A fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/9396H/13/)